# FindVisualChild cannot find Grid in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to use a basic implementation of "FindVisualChild" for WPF in order to find a specific `Grid` that exists within a `DataTemplate` of a `ListBox`.

The implementation is as follows:

```
private DependencyObject FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj, string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((FrameworkElement)obj).Name);
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
        //not a framework element or is null
        if (fe == null) return null;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fe.Name))
            Console.WriteLine(fe.Name);
        if (child is T && fe.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return child;
        else
        {
            //Not found it - search children
            DependencyObject nextLevel = FindVisualChild<T>(child, name);
            if (nextLevel != null)
                return nextLevel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My issue is that this code was working yesterday to find a `Grid` that I have defined in the `DataTemplate` with the name "MainTermServListGrid" as shown here:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TermServListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TermServs}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="MainTermServListGrid">
            //code here
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, today when I try to use the same method to find that `Grid`, the result is always null. If I debug and step through the code, it looks like it is not even finding any of the items that exist within the `DataTemplate`.

I am calling the `FindVisualChild` method right after I populate the `ListBox` with items. Could it be that I am not waiting long enough and the window does not have enough time to finish initializing and presenting the new items in the list box before I am trying to find a specific child within that listbox?

If that is the case, would a simple call to `await Task.Delay(500)` work to give the UI enough time to finish loading? Or am I doing something totally wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was right in assuming I was not giving the UI enough time to finish loading. I believe it is due to the fact that I was populating the `ListBox` with items using a particular method, and at the end of that method I was raising an `Event` which triggered the search in the `Window`'s code-behind.

Because there was never a period if time between finishing the loading of the items and the event being raised to look for them, I dont think the ui had time to finish initializing everything.

Basically all I did to fix the issue in my event handler was the following:

```
private async void ViewModelOnListPopulated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    //Continue on to find the visual child...
}
```